# Bootstrap template - item-list-type: square not working

Tags: css

I've gone through the bootstrap css file twice now and debugger is not showing anything that overwrites the code I'm using either.

This is the list I've got:

```
              <ul class="list-inline">              
                <li><a href="#april15" class="months">April '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#may15" class="months">May '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#june15" class="months">June '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#july15" class="months">July '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#august15" class="months">August '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#september15" class="months">Sep '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#october15" class="months">Oct '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#november15" class="months">Nov '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#december15" class="months">Dec '15</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2016" class="months">Q1 '16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2016" class="months">Q2 '16</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2016" class="months">2016</a></li>
              </ul>
```

This is the  css

```
.list-inline {
 background-color: #fff;
 width: 100%;
 padding:0;
 list-style-type: square;
 }
```

This is the  css

```
{
padding-left:20px;
font-size:16px;
text-align: center;
color: #222;    
}
```

I've used every trick I could find, such as !important, playing around with margins/paddings, but nothing's changed the fact that my squares are not appearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order bullet to be drawn on list DOM element that element shall have `display:list-item` declared. It seems that your `<li>`s have other display values. I suspect inline, or inline-block.

You will probably need to use ::before pseudo element or background image with square.

Update:

```css
li { display:inline-block; }
li::before { content:"\25aa" }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I indeed noticed while coding (should've mentioned this) that the problem occurs whenever I change to display:block. If I use display:list-item, the lists is sorted vertically which ruins everything though, but the squares are shown.

Comment: Works flawlessly now, thank you! I'm not familiar with the ::before thing, I will read up on it now though, since you saved my day by using it.

Comment: c-smile, is there a way to specify this to the list only? My navigation bars is rather broken now and I'm not sure how I can prevent that from happening.

Comment: Assign id to that list element. Say `<ul id="foo">...</ul>`. After that you can use id based rules:  
`#foo > li { display:inline-block; }
#foo > li::before { content:"\25aa" }`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.list-inline li {
   list-style-type: square;
}
```

You need to target the li not the ul

As c-smile suggested it is inheritable so you could just remove the padding from the ul and this also works.

Comment: `list-style-type` is an inheritable property so you can define it on container.